# Issue installing ceedling in Windows 11

Tags: ruby, windows, ceedling

I have tried to install ceedling for Windows 11. But come across this error:

```
Failed to load C:/ProgramData/gemrc, (<unknown>): control characters are not allowed at line 1 column 1
```

I installed Ruby 3.1.3.1 (x64) from here https://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/
Then I ran:

```
gem install ceedling
```

Any ideas on how to install ceedling correctly would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error is telling you that the file `C:\ProgramData\gemrc` has invalid data in it at line 1, column 1. You have most likely edited this file improperly when installing Ruby because this is a default file with a default configuration that should have been created when you installed Ruby.

You should try these steps in order:

1. Inspect the file to see what invalid characters exist at that position, comparing it to [some default gemrc files](https://gist.github.com/jch/1331576), and remove any invalid characters, or:
2. Rename the file and try again, or:
3. Remove the file and reinstall Ruby from scratch so that the file is created from scratch

Comment: I deleted gemrc from C:\ProgramData where it was and tried gem install ceedling again and it looks like its worked now, thanks! Never used or installed these tools before so all new!